# General method to find exact confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Say we have a beta random variable with pdf, $f_X (x) = e^{-x/\theta}/\theta$ for positive $x $. Find the exact confidence interval of $\theta$ with 95% confidence.

A solution to this says

$$\mathbb{P}(a \leq \frac{X}{\theta} \leq b) \geq 0.95$$
where $c_i $ is real.

Then the answer falls out after when the cdf of $X/\theta $ is found.

My question is why that inequality came about? Why does it consider a transformed random variable? I thought it would be

$$\mathbb{P}(c \leq \theta \leq d) \geq 0.95$$
where $c $ and $d $ are functions with respect to $X $.

Thanks

Comment: $a\le X/\theta\le b$ is equivalent to $X/b\le\theta\le X/a$.

Comment: Ahh thanks! What a miss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Typographical errors:* Your random variable has an exponential (not beta) distribution
with mean $\theta.$ Also, I don't see the relevance of $c_i.$

**Confidence interval of exponential data**

Then $Y = X/\theta$ has an exponential distribution with mean 1,
and CDF $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = 1 - e^{-y},$ for $y > 0.$
This makes it easy to find numerical values for $a$ and $b.$

Then you are correct, that you need to solve (some books say 'pivot')
to isolate $\theta$ between the two confidence limits:
$$P(a \le X/\theta \le b) = 
P\left(\frac{1}{b} \le \frac{\theta}{X} \le \frac{1}{a}\right)
= P\left(\frac{X}{b} \le \theta \le \frac{X}{a}\right) = 0.95.$$

*Note:* A more useful confidence interval (CI) is for data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, where the $X_i$ are iid $Exp(mean = \theta).$ Then
$\bar X$ has a gamma distribution, which can be used to find $a$ and $b,$ and similar manipulation can give a CI for $\theta$ in terms of $\bar X.$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and extension on the matter. I have a small query - by definition of confidence intervals on this question, there are two choices to pick, (for $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$),

$$P(a_1 X \leq \theta \leq a_2 X) = 0.95$$

and

$$P(\frac{b_1}{X} \leq \theta \leq \frac{b_2}{X}) = 0.95$$

We pick the first one because of foresight that the random variable, $X/\theta$ produces a simpler CDF?

Comment: Between these two $\theta$ is the mean in the first and the rate in the second. They are not equivalent expressions.